# How to sort one int array and a string array to one sorted string array

Tags: java, arrays

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String firstName[] = { "Adaline", "Almeda", "Alyce", "Amos", "Anneliese", "Antoinette" };
        String lastName[] = { "Aker", "Austria", "Arvin", "Amerine", "Atnip", "Abbate" };
        int englishGrade[] = { 99, 86, 72, 90, 73, 84 };

        for (int i = 0; i < lastName.length; i++) {
            Arrays.sort(lastName);
            System.out.println(lastName[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
Antoinette Abbate 84
Adaline Aker 99
Alyce Arvin 72
Amos Amerine 90 
Anneliese Atnip 73 
Almeda Austria 86
```

Sorted by last name want to make so it outputs above ex. Show me the steps towards me finding the answer.

Comment: it is always recommended to add simple input and output example

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You should have a single array of Student objects, and sort that unique array by the last name of the students. Java is an OO language.

Comment: Don't use parallel arrays. Java is an Object-Oriented language. Use it. Create a class with 3 fields, then sort array of those.

Comment: Please provide some details to make it more concise

Comment: The formatting hurts my soul.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting if you want to tell me how to make it look better then thanks. I want to sort it by last name and have the first name and english grade be sorted along with it. So the output looks like the ex. I have written.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should avoid using arrays like that. It is better to create object e.g. `PersonGrade` and create one instance of it for each person.

```
public static final class PersonGrade {

    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final int englishGrade;

    public PersonGrade(String firstName, String lastName, int englishGrade) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.englishGrade = englishGrade;
    }
}
```

Then define comparator that you need, e.g. compare by last name asc:

```
private static final Comparator<PersonGrade> COMPARE_BY_LAST_NAME = (p1, p2) -> p1.lastName.compareToIgnoreCase(p2.lastName);
```

And finally you can add all your parsons to the list and then sort it using given comparator or create `TreeSet` with given comparator and add all your persons to it (this is binary try and all your persons will be automatically sorted):

```
Set<PersonGrade> persons = new TreeSet<>(COMPARE_BY_LAST_NAME);
persons.add(new PersonGrade("Adaline", "Aker", 99));
persons.add(new PersonGrade("Almeda", "Austria", 86));
persons.add(new PersonGrade("Alyce", "Arvin", 72));
persons.add(new PersonGrade("Amos", "Amerine", 90));
persons.add(new PersonGrade("Anneliese", "Atnip", 73));
persons.add(new PersonGrade("Antoinette", "Abbate", 84));

persons.forEach(person -> System.out.println(person.firstName + ' ' + person.lastName + ' ' + person.englishGrade));
```

**P.S.**

This is how you can solve your problem using arrays.

```
public static void sortByLastName(String[] firstNames, String[] lastNames, int[] englishGrades) {
    class PersonGrade implements Comparable<PersonGrade> {

        final String firstName;
        final String lastName;
        final int englishGrade;

        public PersonGrade(String firstName, String lastName, int englishGrade) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.englishGrade = englishGrade;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(PersonGrade p) {
            return lastName.compareToIgnoreCase(p.lastName);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return firstName + ' ' + lastName + ' ' + englishGrade;
        }
    }

    Set<PersonGrade> persons = new TreeSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < firstNames.length; i++)
        persons.add(new PersonGrade(firstNames[i], lastNames[i], englishGrades[i]));

    int i = 0;

    for (PersonGrade person : persons) {
        firstNames[i] = person.firstName;
        lastNames[i] = person.lastName;
        englishGrades[i] = person.englishGrade;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also override `Comparable.compareTo` and `toString` in your class avoiding unnecessary lambdas in this particular case. Thus you will be able to print your results simply by calling `persons.forEach (System.out::println)`

Comment: Yes, but this is less flexible soultion.

Comment: I need to use the arrays I have written and sort it by last name with first name and english grade sorted along with it. I want to know if there is a method that allows me to do this.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Indeed. Although doing this *homework task* it would be very useful for original poster to learn some OOP by implementing an interface and overriding some methods.

Comment: @ETO is there a website to learn OOP and if so can you provide links?

Comment: **Object-Oriented Analysis and Design with Applications (3rd Edition)** by Grady Booch